# USB Drive's folders disappeared but space still ocupied

Tags: windows-8, usb

My USB drive had viruses. I scanned and fixed all of them. But now all my files have disappeared. They are not hidden and the space in the properties shows 15% used just like it was before. I tried the following command in my drive in the command prompt:

```
attrib -h -s /s /d *.*
```

like several sites suggested but it gives the following error:

```
unable to change attribute - G:\ \Thumbs.us\com1.<d3e34h21-9d75-101a-8c3d-00aa001a1652>
unable to change attribute - G:\ \Thumbs.us\com1.<2227a280-3aea-1069-a2de-08002b30309d>
```

What should I do? All there is in my f=drive now is some Thumbs file and `Found.000`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your MFT (Master File Table) has been destroyed.

What I would do is use a program like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) and scan it for any "erased" documents that it can recover, and restore them to your local HD, after you have recovered everything you can/want, format the flash drive and move those files back over.

Comment: could u brief me up with the process. i have a lot of important data in it. and i am not great with technical language. :P

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a LiveCD of one of the Linux distros and see if it will let you copy/rename the folders to another location and restore their visibility...

Answer (score -1):

It happened also to me with a USB drive. I decide to deep format it and the drive come back correctly.

If you have no important data on that drive you can try to restore it to save the drive.